# Double pointer assigning char array value to char array, of structure using char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, singly-linked-list

I have this function in which i am trying to assign values to the members of the structure.

```
  void Add(NodeDef **Head, char *Data){        
       ptrHead=(struct Node **)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         (*Head)->Data=*(Data);
           (*Head)->NextNode=NULL;
}
```

I am calling this fuction like that

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    AddToLinkedList( &Head, iData[i].name);
```

`iData` is member of a structure which stores data as strings (`char iData[50]`).

Now i am getting an error like

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
  (*Head)->Data=*(Data);
```

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `iData[]`. My guess is that you wanna copy the string in `iData[i].name` to `(*Head)->Data`, but thats not how you copy strings.

Comment: what alternative can be used instead of `malloc()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message the type of struct member `Data` ( in `(*Head)->Data=*(Data);` is array and you are assigning an char value to it.

Since you pass *name*, what you most likely wanted to use is `strcpy()` there:

```
     strcpy((*Head)->Data, Data);
```

Or if you want to store only a single char then you need to change the type of `Data` in the structure to `char` from `char[N]`.

Also, see [what's wrong with casting malloc's return value?](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)